# JOIN over four tables in Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is my issue what i posted to Symfony forum, but since it didn't get any feedback from there, lets try here :)

I have four entities: AdminBundle:Employee, AuthBundle:Login, AdminBundle:Employeephone and AdminBundle:EmployeeEmail.

Of course they have relatons to each other:

**Employee Entity**

```
/**
* @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $login
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Crm\AuthBundle\Entity\Login", mappedBy="employee_id", cascade={"persist"})
*/
protected $login;
/**
* @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $phone
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Crm\AdminBundle\Entity\EmployeePhone", mappedBy="employee_id", cascade={"persist"})
*/
protected $phone;
/**
* @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $email
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Crm\AdminBundle\Entity\EmployeeEmail", mappedBy="employee_id", cascade={"persist"})
*/
protected $email;
```

**Login Entity**

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Crm\AdminBundle\Entity\Employee", inversedBy="login", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id") 
*/
protected $employee;
```

**Phone Entity**

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Crm\AdminBundle\Entity\Employee", inversedBy="login", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $employee;
```

**Email Entity**

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Crm\AdminBundle\Entity\Employee", inversedBy="login", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $employee;
```

Now i want to run query what gets list of all users with their primary phone and email (only one is primary), in SQL i would write this query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `login`
LEFT JOIN `employee` on `login`.`employee_id` = `employee`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `employeephone` on `employee`.`id` = `employeephone`.`employee_id`
LEFT JOIN `employeeemail` on `employee`.`id` = `employeeemail`.`employee_id`
WHERE `employeephone`.`is_primary`=1 
AND `employeeemail`.`is_primary`=1
```

But i can't figure out, how it should look like on Doctrine world.
I tried to do it like this:

```
class EmployeeRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function getAllEmployees() {
        $dql = "SELECT e, l, p, m FROM AuthBundle:Login l
                JOIN l.employee e
                JOIN e.phone p  
                JOIN e.email m";
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
        try {
            return $query->getArrayResult();
        } catch (DoctrineORMNoResultException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

But it gives me little nice error:

> Notice: Undefined index: employee_id in
>   C:\wamp\www\Symphony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker.php
>   line 826

I've tried several other methods, but all of them lead me to different errors. So how to do it correctly ? After endless hours of googel'ing i havent figured it out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map the associations by the variable's name instead of the column's name.

```
/**
 * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $login
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Crm\AuthBundle\Entity\Login", mappedBy="employee")
 */
 protected $login;
```

It should be `employee` and not `employee_id`.

Also your inversedBy annotations are not properly set.. They should respectively point to `login`, `phone` and `email`.

`inversedBy` and `mappedBy` is meant to reference the variable at the opposite side of the association.